# Using multiple marker clusterers in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I have a number of markers in a map and i cluster them by category. I created one array per category for the markers so i have multiple clusterers on my map. Can i create an event handler passing the clusterer as a variable?
For example this is one of my event handlers:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'mouseover', function (cluster)
```

Could i create such a handler using clusterer as a variable so i can use it for all my objects (mc1, mc2, mc3 ....)?

Is using multiple clusterers a good practice or i should implement it another way?

Maybe i should be more specific. Assume that we want to show on a map, cities from all states in USA. At the first level, we want to see a cluster on each state and with mouseover on the cluster the sum of population from all cities in it.
My thought is to create a clusterer per state. Is this right or i 'm starting with a wrong decision?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I see no problem with adding multiple clusters, although it might get tough performancewise at some point. As your case seems possibly a little bit more complicated, I would recommend to have a look at the marker manager: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html